# Prove coherence condition of closed category from monoidal closed category

Tags: category-theory

I am reading Closed Categories, Eilenberg and Kelly, 65 and get extremely confused by one equivalence proof of coherence conditions.

In particular, I am struggling with the following equivalence:

[image]

where $\pi : Hom(A \otimes B , C) \to Hom(A, [B , C])$ is the usual natural isomorphism induced by the adjoint pair $-\otimes B \dashv [B , -]$. $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ are the unit and counit transformations of the adjoint.

$a, l, r$ are the associator, left unitor and right unitor of the monodal component.

$L : [B,C] \to [ [A , B], [A , C]]$ is the internal left composition transformation.

$p : [A \otimes B, C] \to [A, [B , C]]$ is the currying transformation.

$i : A \to [ u, A ]$ is the natural isomorphism, where $u$ is the monoidal unit.

In the paper, it claims that the diagrams in the image are equivalent. I understand that MCC4 and CC4 are equivalent and they imply MC4. But I have got no idea why MC4 also implies MCC4 or CC4.

In particular, in the proof in the paper, computation 1 is performed. The computation begins with applying $\pi$ twice to MC4, which eventually concludes

$$p[r , 1]\eta = [1, i] \eta$$

then the paper concludes $p[r, 1] = [1, i]$ which corresponds to the bottom left corner of the diagram on the right. This step confuses me. How does this work?

I also know MCC4 and CC4 equals to $\pi(\pi(\epsilon r))$, but that doesn't seem to help solve the problem.

Comment: aha! I think I figured it out. I suppose the rule is to ask a question so that there is better chance to figure it out by myself.

Comment: You can even record here your answer as an answer.

Comment: I will. I will choose it up in Ages tomorrow and answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how the proof above works but there is another way to prove it by making use of the naturality of $i$.

consider the following computation

$$
\begin{align}
p[r,1] &= \pi(\pi(\epsilon r)) \tag*{naturality of $\pi$} \\
&= \pi([1,\epsilon] \circ\pi(r)) \\
&= \pi([1,\epsilon] \circ i) \tag*{naturality of $i$}\\
&= \pi(i\epsilon) \tag*{naturality of $\epsilon$}\\
&= \pi(\pi^{-1}[1,i]) \\
&= [1,i]
\end{align}
$$

this is mechanized in

https://github.com/agda/agda-categories/blob/master/Categories/Category/Monoidal/Closed/IsClosed.agda#L265